# How to remove one of the two duplicate blocks in a file?

Tags: python, regex, file-io, duplicates

I have a difficult problem. I know there are so many 're' masters in python out there. So please help me. I have a huge log file. The format is something like this:

```
[text hello world yadda

          lines lines lines

          exceptions]

[something i'm not interested in]

[text hello world yadda

          lines lines lines

          exceptions]
```

And so on... 
So Block 1 and 3 are same. And there are multiple cases like this. My ques is how can I read this file and write in an output file only the unique blocks? If there's a duplicate, it should be written only once. And sometimes there are multiple blocks in between two duplicate blocks. I'm actually pattern matching and this is the code as of now. It only matches the pattern but doesn't do anything about duplicates.

```
import re
import sys
from itertools import islice
try:
   if len(sys.argv) != 3:
      sys.exit("You should enter 3 parameters.")
   elif sys.argv[1] == sys.argv[2]:
      sys.exit("The two file names cannot be the same.")
   else:
       file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
       file1 = open(sys.argv[2],"w")
       java_regex = re.compile(r'[java|javax|org|com]+?[\.|:]+?', re.I)  # java 
       at_regex = re.compile(r'at\s', re.I)    # at

       copy = False  # flag that control to copy or to not copy to output

       for line in file:
          if re.search(java_regex, line) and not (re.search(r'at\s', line, re.I) or re.search(r'mdcloginid:|webcontainer|c\.h\.i\.h\.p\.u\.e|threadPoolTaskExecutor|caused\sby', line, re.I)):
              # start copying if "java" is in the input
              copy = True
          else:
              if copy and not re.search(at_regex, line):
                  # stop copying if "at" is not in the input
                  copy = False

          if copy:
              file1.write(line)



       file.close()
       file1.close()

except IOError:
       sys.exit("IO error or wrong file name.")
except IndexError:
       sys.exit('\nYou must enter 3 parameters.') #prevents less than 3 inputs which is mandatory
except SystemExit as e:                       #Exception handles sys.exit()
       sys.exit(e)
```

I don't care if this has to be in this code(removing duplicates). It can be in a separate .py file also. Doesn't matter
This is the original snippet of the log file:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Uncaught BPEL fault http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Server     
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1326) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1052) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.java:415) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:597) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:537) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:403) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:188) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]
com.hcentive.utils.exception.HCRuntimeException: Unable to Find User Profile:null
    at com.hcentive.agent.service.AgentServiceImpl.getAgentByUserProfile(AgentServiceImpl.java:275) ~[agent-service-core-4.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.hcentive.agent.service.AgentServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$e3caddab.invoke(<generated>) ~[cglib-2.2.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191) ~[cglib-2.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) ~[spring-tx-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64) ~[spring-security-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Uncaught BPEL fault http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Server      
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1326) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1052) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.java:415) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:597) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:537) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:403) ~[org.apache.axis2.jar:na]  



And so on and on....
```

Comment: Ok, if I understand well you want to obtain the first line and the line which begins with `com.hcentive...` but not the second `javax.xml.ws....` because it is a duplicate. All lines that starts with `at ` are excluded?

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte No. I want the first line "javax..." and all the "at"...lines after that. Then I want the line "com..." and all the "at" lines after that. But after that if you see the rest of the block is a duplicate of the first one. So after that I dont want the "javax"...line and all the "at"... lines as they were already repeated....

Comment: So basically by block I mean a section appearing with javax or com and all the "at" lines after that until another "javax" or "com" arrives. Now if one block is completely identical to each other, I want it to be removed once and just keep it once.

Comment: it's more clear now, how many lines has the destination file with duplicates? (- or +)

Comment: Casimir et Hippolyte almost like 10k....please dude...tell me how to do this thing \....i'm stuck....

Comment: Casimir et Hippolyte Any ideas?

Comment: Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: What about http://regex101.com/r/uP1aZ3 ? It's PCRE, but if your regex allows for recursion (?1), `^((?! ).*\n(?: .*\n)+)(?!\1)(?1)` seems to work with the data you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove duplicate blocks with this:

```
import re
yourstr = r'''
[text hello world yadda

      lines lines lines

      exceptions]

[something i'm not interested in]

[text hello world yadda

      lines lines lines

      exceptions]
'''
pat = re.compile(r'\[([^]]+])(?=.*\[\1)', re.DOTALL)
result = pat.sub('', yourstr)
```

Note that only the last block is preserved, If you want the first you must reverse the string and use this pattern:

```
 (][^[]+)\[(?=.*\1\[)
```

and then reverse the string again.

Comment: @sagarnildass: you can easily adapt the example.

Comment: Sorry to misguide you, but my file doesn't start with the word "Block". I just did that for convenience. Actually I am not an expert on python. So i would be glad if you can modify my code to show exactly where to put your code. And please edit your code now that you know the blocks doesn't start with the word "block". Thanks a ton!

Comment: It says no method called gsub. Also what do I put in place of yourstr?

Comment: @sagarnildass: sorry it is `sub` not `gsub`, my mistake.

Comment: thanks man. I have another question. What do I put in place of yourstr?

Comment: `yourstr` is the text from your log file.

Comment: @sam sullivan but if i write 'line' in place of yourstr, the whole file gets copied again with the duplicates. So how do i get rid of them?

Comment: Casimir et Hippolyte could you please specify what exactly should I wrie in place of youstr? If I write 'line', the whole file gets copied again with the duplicates. So how do i get rid of them?

Comment: @sagarnildass: The code I gave can't work if you process a file line by line, it works only with the whole content of your destination file. I edited my post with your example string to illustrate this fact. If you want an more adapted code to your situation, please post a real sample (edit your post) of a log. It's the only thing I need.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte Post edited. As you can see the first and the third block are exactly same. In that case I only want to keep one of them. The only thing is all the duplicate blocks are very long and they are all different. So it will not be possible for me to store them as a string like you showed above as you can understand.In this present scenario what should I do.?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hashing algorithm like in hashlib and a dictionary that looks like this: {123456789: True}
the value is not important but a dict makes it significantly faster than a list if its a big file.

Anyway you can hash each block as you come along it and store it in the dictionary as long as its not in the dictionary.  If it is in the dictionary then ignore the block. That's assuming your blocks are structured absolutely identical.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please modify my code so as to portray your idea? I'm new to this.